# Find the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_{125} \times \mathbb{Z} $

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Find all subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_{125} \times \mathbb{Z}$ up to isomorphism

My try:

I know there are subgroups of the form $H_1 \times H_2 \times H_3 $ when $H_1\le\mathbb{Z}_5  , H_2\le\mathbb{Z}_{125} , H_3\le\mathbb{Z}$.

How can I find the subgroups which are not of this form and how can I know that I found all of them?

Comment: In the finite case, the order of subgroups has to divide the order of the group, so $Z_5$ has no nontrivial subgroup, $Z$ has infinite subgroups. In the case of $Z_n$ specifically, its subgroups are up to isomorphism the subgroups of orders that divide $n$. So $Z_6$ has non trivial subgroups of orders $2,3$ namely $<2>$ and $<3>$.

Comment: Goursat's lemma may help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goursat%27s_lemma